# What is the origin of this huge degeneracy in this almost free fermion model?

Tags: symmetry, conformal-field-theory, second-quantization

Consider the following second quantized Hamiltonian:
$$H=\int_S \frac{1}{2m}(\partial_x-i\partial_y)\psi^\dagger_{\mathbf{r}}~(\partial_x+i\partial_y)\psi_{\mathbf{r}}~\mathrm{d}^2\mathbf{r},$$
where $S$ is an arbitrary region in 2D plane and $\psi_\mathbf{r}$ is a second quantized fermion field. Notice that $H$ differs from the canonical kinetic term by only a boundary term
$$H=\int_S \left\{\frac{1}{2m}\nabla\psi^\dagger\cdot\nabla\psi~\mathrm+i\left[\partial_x(\psi^\dagger\partial_y\psi)-\partial_y(\psi^\dagger\partial_x\psi)\right]\right\}\mathrm{d}^2\mathbf{r}$$
however, it seems that the spectrum of $H$ has much more degeneracy. Notice that
$$\{(\partial_x+i\partial_y)\psi_{\mathbf{r}},\psi^\dagger_f\equiv\int_S f(z')\psi^\dagger_\mathbf{r'}~\mathrm{d}^2\mathbf{r'}\}=2\partial_{\bar{z}}f(z)=0,$$
where $z=x+i y$ and $f(z)$ is an analytic function of $z$ in region $S$. It follows that $[\psi^\dagger_f,H]=0$, thus for any eigenstate $|E_k\rangle$ of $H$, the state $\psi^\dagger_f|E_k\rangle$ is another eigenstate with exactly the same energy.

If we take $S$ to be a square region with periodic boundary condition, from Liouville's theorem we know that a function that is analytic everywhere in $S$ and periodic in $x,y$ must be a constant, thus $\psi^\dagger_f\propto\psi^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{0}}$, and this is consistent with $E_{\mathbf{k}}=|\mathbf{k}|^2/2m$.

However, for more general region $S$ with open boundary it seems that there is a huge number of zero energy modes $\psi^\dagger_f$, and thus a huge degeneracy in the spectrum. Where does this degeneracy come from, is it due to something like conformal symmetry? Is this model already studied somewhere?

Update: I have found that under conformal transformation $\psi_{z}\to \phi_{w(z)}$, $H$ is transformed to 
$$H=\int_{w(S)} \frac{1}{2m}(\partial_u-i\partial_v)\phi^\dagger_{w}~(\partial_u+i\partial_v)\phi_{w}~\mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}v,$$
where $w=u+iv$. But I have no idea how this "invariance" is related to the degeneracy.